# Translating Stata to R yields different results

Tags: r, dplyr, stata

I am trying to translate a Stata code from a paper into R.

The Stata code looks like this:

```
g tau = year - temp2 if temp2 > temp3 & (bod<. | do<. | lnfcoli<.)
```

My R translation looks like this:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(tau = if_else((temp2 > temp3) & 
                         (is.na(bod) | is.na(do) | is.na(lnfcoli)), 
                       year - temp2,
                       NA_integer_))
```

The problem is that when I run each code I get different results.

This is the result I get when I run the code in Stata:

```
1   Year |  temp2  |  temp3 | bod | do  | lnfcoli | tau |
2   1986 |  1995   |  1986  | 3.2 | 7.2 | 2.1.    |  -9 |
```

This is the result I get when I run the code in R:

```
1   Year |  temp2  |  temp3 | bod | do  | lnfcoli | tau |
2   1986 |  1995   |  1986  | 3.2 | 7.2 | 2.1.    |  NA |
```

Do you know what might be wrong with my R code or what should I modify to get the same output?

Comment: Oh great! Now I feel so dumb! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of `bod`, `do` or `lnfcoli` are missing (`NA`), so your logic returns `FALSE` and returns `NA_integer_` (`false=` in the `if_else`). Stata treats `.` or missing values as positive infinity, so that check is actually looking for **not** missing.

So the equivalent in R/dplyr is probably:

```
data %>%
    mutate(
        tau = if_else(
        (temp2 > temp3) & (!(is.na(bod) | is.na(do) | is.na(lnfcoli))),
        year-temp2,
        NA_integer_
        )
    )

#  year temp2 temp3 bod  do lnfcoli tau
#1 1986  1995  1986 3.2 7.2     2.1  -9
```

Comment: Stata also has a `missing()` function which yields 1 if any argument is missing and 0 otherwise.  Missing for strings is an empty string. Missings for numerics includes `.a` to `.z` which can be used according to user choice to indicate specific kinds of missing, say "Not applicable", "Did not answer", "Instrument broke".  Any non-missing number is regarded as less than any of those.

Comment: @NickCox As generally an R user who uses Stata when it's the right tool for the job, I have been tripped up by differences between the rules. For example, I was surprised that in Stata that `scalar m = . & .` will assign the value of `1` to `m`, rather than `.`. Do you know any resources where the Stata boolean logic rules are set out?

Comment: Non-zero counts as true and zero as false. https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/ and https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1601600117 are riffs on what is conveyed concisely e.g. in [U] 13.2 Operators.